CRC residue verification fails
I am developing a light-weight CRC calculator for all 8-, 16-, and 32-bit versions that I found in the online catalogue:
https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm
I'm confused by the residue parameter. As I understand, its value defines the CRC register value when it is calculated for the whole message plus its CRC. However, I cannot get this check to work for some (most) algorithms.
We can use the following online tool for a quick check:
https://crccalc.com/
We can use the standard test message b"123456789" which is in hex 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x36 0x37 0x38 0x39. When CRC is calculated for this message, the result equals the check parameter. Now if I append the check parameter to the standard test message, I expect to get the residue parameter. However, this does not work for about half the algorithms.
Here is an example what I get for couple of messages when I input the standard test message plus the check parameter for that particular algorithm.
==========================================================================
Algorithm        Check    Append      Residue  Result for TEST + Append
==========================================================================
CRC-16/ARC       0xBB3D   0x3D 0xBB   0x0000   0x0000
CRC-16/ARC       0xBB3D   0xBB 0x3D   0x0000   0xC2E3    *DOES NOT MATCH*
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
CRC-16/CDMA2000  0x4C06   0x06 0x4C   0x0000   0xA527    *DOES NOT MATCH*
CRC-16/CDMA2000  0x4C06   0x4C 0x06   0x0000   0x0000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
CRC-16/DNP       0xEA82   0x82 0xEA   0x66C5   0x993A    *DOES NOT MATCH*
CRC-16/DNP       0xEA82   0xEA 0x82   0x66C5   0x2BD4    *DOES NOT MATCH*
==========================================================================

However, the CRC-16/DNP does seem to always result in 0x993A whenever the CRC is appended to the message. It is similar for other algorithms.
What am I missing here?

The residue is defined to be the CRC before the final exclusive-or is applied. The final exclusive-or for CRC-16/DNP is 0xffff. The complement of 0x66c5 is 0x993a.
From your table you can see that it works when the CRC bytes are appended in the correct order (and when the final exclusive-or is zero, since you weren't taking that into account). The correct order is little-endian when the CRC is reflected, and big-endian when it is not reflected.

This did the trick, thank you! Any reason in particular why residue is defined as "CRC before final XOR is applied"? If the algorithm is applied the way I described it in my question, it should have been compared to residue ^ xorout instead of just residue (I was doing the latter). IMO this notation just adds to the confusion..

I don't know the whole sordid history, but the definition comes from hardware implementations, where the "residue" is what is left over in the CRC register after the CRC is run through it. So that is before any final exclusive-or.

Then if I get this right, hardware implementations of CRC calculations do not include this final XOR, but it is done "later" in software? What is the significance of the final XOR anyway?

A hardware implementation would still need the final exclusive-or when sending, but when receiving it could skip it, instead comparing the register contents with the (pre-xor) residue.

An initial value of zero has the bad property that a string of zero bytes will not change the CRC register, with a result independent of the number of initial zero bytes. A non-zero initial value avoids this, with the register changing and the result depending on the number of zero bytes. So what does that have to do with the final exclusive-or? Well, now an empty input (no bytes) has a non-zero CRC. It seems more appropriate somehow for an empty input to have a zero CRC, hence it is very common to have a final exclusive-or equal to the initial value. Then an empty input has a zero CRC.

Hi Mark, I'm still working on the residue verification. I managed to get the residue verification to work for (almost) all models from the CRC catalogue. However, for the following models I could not get the expected residue, even with other tools such as RevEng: CRC-4/INTERLAKEN, CRC-5/EPC-C1G2, CRC-5/USB, CRC-6/CDMA2000-A, CRC-6/CDMA2000-B, CRC-10/CDMA2000, CRC-11/FLEXRAY, CRC-12/CDMA2000, CRC-30/CDMA, CRC-31/PHILIPS. I created a message, calculated CRC, appended the CRC to the message, and then calculated CRC before the final XOR for the new message. The residue for these is not consistent.

You would need to ask a new question with an example calculation for at least one of those.
